# Correct way to validate the creation of multiple folders and files in C ++

Tags: c++

I am working on a personal project, **one of the first steps that my program executes is to create some folders and files when the user applies a command through the console**.

For example. The user executes the command **`emi -start`** through the console, this triggers the creation of the following files and folders:

- **emi_base**

  - emi_database

    - emi_main_db_file.csv
    - emi_catch_db_file.csv
    - emi_temp_db_file.csv
  - emi_version

    - emi_main_version_folder
    - emi_catch_version_folder
    - emi_temp_version_folder
  - emi_config

    - emi_config_file.txt
    - emi_ignore_file.txt
    - emi_repo_file.txt

For this to be possible I use a code similar to this:

```
    // Creating folder emi_base
    bool emi_directory_created = fs::create_directory(emi_default_path);
    // Creating folder emi_database and its corresponding files
    bool db_directory_created = fs::create_directory(db_default_path);
    ofstream db_main_file_ostrm(db_main_file, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    ofstream db_catch_file_ostrm(db_catch_file, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    ofstream db_temp_file_ostrm(db_temp_file, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    // Creating folder emi_version and its corresponding sub-folders
    bool version_directory_created = fs::create_directory(version_default_path);
    bool version_main_directory_created = fs::create_directory(version_main_folder);
    bool version_catch_directory_created = fs::create_directory(version_catch_folder);
    bool version_temp_directory_created = fs::create_directory(version_temp_folder);
    // Creating folder emi_config and its corresponding files
    bool config_directory_created = fs::create_directory(config_default_path);

    if (emi_directory_created &&
            db_directory_created &&
            db_main_file_ostrm &&
            db_catch_file_ostrm &&
            db_temp_file_ostrm &&
            version_directory_created &&
            version_main_directory_created &&
            version_catch_directory_created &&
            version_temp_directory_created &&
            config_directory_created) {
                // Code that is executed after validating that all files and folders were created correctly.
    }
```

Well, for now everything works correctly, however, I do not know if that is the best way to validate that the folders and the respective files have been created correctly, **it seems to me that putting all those Booleans in a conditional is not the right thing to do**.

**Is there a better way to do this? Is there a better way to validate the creation of multiple folders and files at once or in sequence?**

Hope someone can give this newbie some feedback :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `fs::create_directory` is [`std::filesystem::create_directory`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem/create_directory), then `fs::create_directory(<path>)` throws an exception if the directory cannot be created, you don't need to check its return value:

> The overload that does not take a `std::error_code&` parameter throws `filesystem_error` on underlying OS API errors, constructed with `p` as the first path argument and the OS error code as the error code argument.

But you do need to check that the files were opened successfully with [`ofstream::is_open`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ofstream/is_open) call. You may like to create a helper function that opens an `ofstream` and checks whether that succeeded and then return `ofstream`, in C++11 `ofstream` is moveable and hence can be returned by value. E.g.:

```
std::ofstream open_ofstream(char const* filename) {
    std::ofstream f(filename, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    if(!f.is_open())
        throw std::system_error{errno, std::system_category(), filename}; // Hoping that std::ofstream didn't mangle errno.
        // or throw std::filesystem::filesystem_error{"failed to open", filename, std::error_code{errno,  std::system_category()}};    
    return f;
}
```

---

If all your directories and files reside in one top-level directory, you may like to create it with a different name first, create the directory/file structure in it and initialize the files, and then rename the top-level directory to its final name. So that when the top-level directory exists that means that it is correctly initialized and is ready for use.

Comment: It might sound silly, but I'm not done going through all the basic C ++ topics yet, so I haven't gotten to the exception handling yet, however I understand the concept. You mean I should use a try / catch to catch the exception in case the creation fails and that would be enough, right?

P.S. Yes, I am using std::filesystem

Comment: @JulioZaravia That depends on what your program should do when it cannot create the files. Throwing an exception that is not handled terminates your application and that's a good start. When you later decide that your program should continue somehow despite errors, then you may like to catch those exceptions or not throw them at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think better way is throw an exception in create_directory funciton if folder creation fail. So you dont need to check every create_directory call. Just one try-catch will be enough.

Comment: I understand, it seems like the correct technique to me, this way I should first create the whole folder structure and validate it using the try / catch.

Another question, in my learning I still don't get to check the exception handling. To create the files I am using ofstream, the ofstream also throws an exception when it can't create a file? if so I could handle everything by a try / catch.

Well, I will check on my own about the ofstream, thanks for your answer.